# Is there a Chrome-like "Waterfall" debugging tool for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a Visual Studio debugger tool that will show me results similar to Chrome's Dev Tools waterfall?

How much time was spent during the whole page load, but including metrics for server side stuff like Generic Handlers and .NET Classes?  How long loops took to complete.  How long it took a generic handler to retrieve, serialise, and return a JSON result.  How long a database request took to complete.  Things like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, visual studio debugger doesn't support these features. You can provide a suggestion here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion

Comment: Not even a profiler of some sort?  Dang.  But this seems like the right answer!  ;-)  Thanks